# How to stream Google Cloud Storage bucket to Big Query with Dataflow without Pub/Sub

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to write a Python script to stream data from my Google Cloud Storage bucket to Big Query with the help of Dataflow pipe line. I am able to start a job but that job is running as batch and not the streaming one and we are not allowed to use Pub/Sub.

Below is the code I am trying with details made generic:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
import re
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
import json

from past.builtins import unicode
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions



# This class has all the functions which facilitate data transposition
class WordExtractingDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WordExtractingDoFn, self).__init__()

    # Create Bigquery Row
   dict function
       return
def run_bq(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    schema1 = your schema
    # All Command Line Arguments being added to the parser
    parser.add_argument(
        '--input', dest='input', required=False,
        default='gs://your-bucket-path/')

    parser.add_argument('--output', dest='output', required=False,
                        default='yourdataset.yourtable')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_args.extend([
        '--runner=DataflowRunner',
        '--project=your-project',
        '--staging_location=gs://your-staging-bucket-path/',
        '--temp_location=gs://your-temp-bucket-path/',
        '--job_name=pubsubbql1',
        '--streaming'
    ])
    pushtobq = WordExtractingDoFn()

    # Pipeline Creation Begins
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))
    (p
     | 'Read from a File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input)
     | 'String To BigQuery Row' >> beam.Map(dict-file)
     | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                    known_args.output,
                    schema=schema2
                )
     )

    # Run Pipeline
    p.run().wait_until_finish()


# Main Method to call
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run_bq()
```

With the above code I am able to create jobs but they are batch jobs, my main motive is to take data from buckets which is in json format and I need to insert it into BigQuery.

Comment: Your question is very short on details. Your example code is not complete, you just copied from an example. Write your own code, test and then come back to StackOverflow when you have a real coding problem that we can help you solve.

Comment: dude i have written that code obviously took structure from some where else tested that code but my problem is it is starting batch flow on google dataflow , i need to know how to initiate a streaming job , i come across a solution that is file watcher but that solution i am not able to write for python code , it is there in java but in python i am not sure